# CodeIgniter settings from database to be accessible on all pages

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a table in my database called settings, with the following structure {id, name, value}.
I want a variable to be available on all pages like $setting[name] => value.... 
I tried putting it on the helper and autoload it, but the helper can't access the db. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: you should be able to get the db from the helper. just add $_ci =& get_instance(); inside you helper function and then use it like $_ci->db->get('mytable');

Comment: I tried that, the following is my code
function settings(){

    $CI = & get_instance();
    $seting_query = $CI->db->query("SELECT * FROM settings");
    $setting = array();
    if($setting_query):
        foreach ($setting_query->result() as $s):
          $setting[$s->name] = $s->value;
        endforeach;
    endif;
    return $setting;
}

$settings = settings()

But the error output is:

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Admin::$db
Filename: helpers/universal_helper.php
Line Number: 7
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object..

Comment: how about trying 
require_once( BASEPATH .'database/DB'. EXT );
$db =& DB();
$query = $db->get( 'table' );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Create a class called MY_Controller which extends CI_Controller and save it in the core folder under application. Then have all your other classes extend MY_Controller instead of CI_Controller.

Then you can set your values in the constructor of MY_Controller

```
<?PHP
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $settings = $this->db->get('settings');
    }
```

This would make $settings available to all your controllers just like you wanted. Just remember the controllers you need those settings in have to extend MY_Controller!

```
class A_new_controller extends MY_Controller {
```